# android studio or eclipse which one is better for the android developer

Tags: android, eclipse

android studio is better than eclipse?Who can tell me. which one is better for me.
now i'm using eclipse for my develop,should i change ide to studio?

Comment: Idea IntelliJ is even better than those two. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: @AmulyaKhare You really don't do your homework, do you? Android Studio IS IDEA with even more Android extensions.

Comment: @Machinarius I know. I have used both. IDEA is more stable as of now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "better". **Period.**

There is freedom of choice as in being able to choose the well-known and famous Eclipse base or the powerhouse IDEA base.

Benefits of Eclipse:

- Used and abused since the start of Android development
- Rock solid stability
- Familiarity for the average Java developer that is just starting to embrace Android

Benefits of Android Studio:

- A lot more context-sensitive help features (Android-specific refactors, Android resource previews in-line, more powerful build system...)
- A cleaner interface
- Powerful key binding system (I heard somewhere you could completely operate IDEA with just a keyboard)

It all boils down to personal choice (Or peer pressure): I find Android Studio to boost my productivity compared to Eclipse but i often find myself fighting the build system or lost (Pretty sure it's caused by my lack of experience with IDEA though) but i really don't want to go back to Eclipse.

I suggest you try both and find which one best adapts to your workflows.